# Height In a Tilted Cappilary tube

Tags: surface-tension, fluid-statics, capillary-action

[image]

If we tilt a cappiliary tube, i had the doubt that would the height rise of fluid change change..? If not why.. and if it would how may we proceed to find the change? I have assumed the condition to be static and fluid is ideal. I want to know would the effective gravity change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tilting the tube "dilutes" the downward force of gravity, just as in the case of a ball rolling down an inclined plane. This allows surface tension to draw the water further up the tube's length, but the position of the meniscus in terms of its vertical height above the surface of the bulk liquid will remain the same.

Comment: If surface tension will be able to pull more, why would the height be same

Comment: Because surface tension is the same. its force gets balanced against gravity.